# When is the fat join a monoidal structure?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff

This question is about the following general construction.

**Definition:**

Let $(\mathcal C, \otimes)$ be a cocomplete, monoidal biclosed category whose unit $\ast$ is terminal. Let $I$ be an "interval" in $\mathcal C$, by which (for now at least), I just mean that $I$ is an object equipped with two maps from the unit, $\bot, \top : \ast \rightrightarrows I$. Since $\ast$ is terminal, these two points have a common retract which I'll denote $t : I \to \ast$.

From this data, define a bifunctor $\diamondsuit : \mathcal C \times \mathcal C \to \mathcal C$ by

$$A \diamondsuit B = A \cup_{A \otimes \{\bot\} \otimes B} (A \otimes I \otimes B) \cup_{A \otimes \{\top\} \otimes B} B$$

That is, we have two maps $id_A \otimes \bot \otimes id_B, id_A \otimes \top \otimes id_B : A \otimes B = A \otimes \ast \otimes B \rightrightarrows A \otimes I \otimes B$; we push out the first map along $id_A \otimes t : A \otimes B \to A \otimes \ast = A$ and we push out the second along $t \otimes id_B : A \otimes B \to \ast \otimes B = B$.

Let's call this bifunctor $\diamondsuit$ the *fat join* (with respect to $\otimes, I$).

**Notes:**

- For instance, when $(\mathcal C, \otimes) = (sSet, \times)$ and $(I, \bot, \top) = (\Delta[1], \partial^1, \partial^0)$, this is precisely what [Joyal calls](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/IMA/Joyal.pdf#page=31) the *fat join* of simplicial sets. [Lurie calls](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/highertopoi.pdf#page=257) this construction the *alternative join*. It is Joyal-weakly-equivalent to the usual join of simplicial sets.
- By localization, Joyal's fat join leads to at least two $\infty$-categorical examples, where $(\mathcal C, \otimes, I) = (Spaces, \times, \ast)$ and $(\mathcal C, \otimes, I) = (Cat_\infty, \times, \Delta[1])$ respectively.
- Another place it would make sense to consider this construction would be when $\mathcal C = Cat_\omega$ is the category of $\omega$-categories, and $\otimes$ is the lax Gray tensor product. Then one might at least hope that the fat join $\diamondsuit$ is equivalent to the usual join of $\omega$-categories constructed by Ara and Maltsiniotis.
- Granted that $\otimes$ is biclosed, it's immediate that $\diamondsuit$ preserves connected colimits in each variable separately. (In the $\infty$-categorical setting, "connected" should instead be "weakly contractible".) Moreover, the initial object of $\mathcal C$ is a two-sided unit for $\diamondsuit$.

**Question 1:** Under what conditions is $\diamondsuit$ a monoidal structure on $\mathcal C$?

**Question 2:** If a monoidal structure is difficult to achieve in general, are there at least natural conditions leading to a multicategory structure (of which the fat join corepresents the binary part)?

- For instance, I believe that when $(\mathcal C, \otimes, I) = (sSet, \times, \Delta[1])$ as above, the construction $\diamondsuit$ is *not* associative. However, in the two localized $\infty$-categorical examples, $\diamondsuit$ *does* yield a monoidal structure (in both cases called the "join").
- Even when $\diamondsuit$ turns out to be a monoidal structure, one does not expect it to be *symmetric* monoidal, or even *braided* monoidal (regardless of whether $\otimes$ is symmetric), as exemplified by the case of $(\mathcal C, \otimes, I) = (Cat_\infty, \times, \Delta[1])$, where one obtains the usual join, a monoidal structure which is about as far from symmetric as one could imagine.
- I suspect maybe the sort of thing one wants to do is to ask for some kind of comultiplication on $I$ (I'm not sure if this should be a comultiplication with respect to $\otimes$, or rather a comultiplication with respect to the "concatenation" monoidal structure $\vee$ on intervals, where $(I, \bot, \top) \vee (I',\bot', \top') = (I \cup_{\ast} I', \bot, \top')$, the pushout taken over the maps $\top$ and $\bot'$), and use that to construct the associator.
- The question seeems to me to be reminiscent of the question of when the smash product on pointed objects in a cartesian closed category yields a monoidal structure. But I'm not sure there's a way to directly deduce results here from results in that setting.

**Question 3:** (this one is much more specific, just throwing it out there): Is it true that the fat join with respect to the lax Gray tensor product recovers the usual join of $\omega$-categories?